# Allow flagging user profiles as spam

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8664/lower-back-pain <-- Example spam profile.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes there's nothing to flag. [This one on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1091023/montre-luxe) for example has bothered me for a while.

Comment: If they haven't posted any spam *content*, what's it hurting? They can use any user name they want.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: They did post spam content. I flagged it and mods already took care of it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment But allowing their accounts to remain (even after removing the spam in question) still allows their spammy website links to remain as well. It's not a very significant issue though.

Comment: You could mention it in your flag on the post, and we'll consider it, or you could post to meta. I don't know if there is a policy or not...

Comment: @lunboks: Not the same thing. That question is asking to flag *people* for *content* violations which are *not* on the user page. This is asking to flag user pages for things which occur on their specific page.

Comment: @Bart: How does it allow "their spammy website links to remain as well"? There are no links if the posts are deleted.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: The user still shows up in user lists. You still see any spammy links on their profile page proper.

Comment: @TheEstablishment go to the profile I link to. The user's website still links to the same spam content. Like I said, not a hugely important issue (particularly since it's not very visible) but it annoys me. Granted, I'm easily annoyed. ;)

Comment: They can't have links in their profile. They don't have the rep for that, and flagging their posts as spam ensures that it stays that way. Besides, they're allowed to put whatever they want as their "website". I could change mine to `getlowerbackpainreliefnow.com` if I wanted to and there's nothing you could do about it!

Comment: Those "links" are not actually *linked* though. It's just text.

Comment: @BillyONeal The particular profile that you've linked has 10 views, and that after you posted here. Is it really a problem (aside from offending my super-sensitive-spidy-internet-rudeness-sense, of course)?

Comment: @dmckee: Huge problem? No. But problem that would be nice to be able to tell moderators about? Yes.

Comment: Trust: when moderators see a bunch of flags showing up on one user's work (and they can and do see this), they'll tend to deal with the source of the problem. Note that new users don't get working links in their profiles for this very reason.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not talking about anything to do with the user's work. That's the thing.

Comment: @Billy: you can't see it, but the user you linked to posted a (apparently machine-generated) answer, and it was deleted. I probably would have just destroyed the user then (and I would now, if we weren't discussing it), but even without that it's safe enough to know that should he return and post again the past history would be immediately visible to the moderators on that site.